# What is wrong with this useReducer react code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a basic shopping cart app with Reactjs. I created a `useContext` file to make the states globally available.

Unfortunately, the objects in the `useReducer` state are not responding to action, except the array of products called 'cart'. The 'amount' and 'total' are not rendering.

Though, the actions can be seen to be updated when I checked the console log. That means I am not returning the right variables.

The action I want to achieve is that when `<MdKeyboardArrowUp>` is clicked, the 'amount' variable should increase by `1`. It increases on console log but not rendered on the page.

**The product list**:

```
export default [
{
id: 1,
title: 'Samsung Galaxy S7',
price: 599.99,
img:
  'https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1583368215/phone-2_ohtt5s.png',
amount: 1,
},
```

**useContext file**

```
import React, {useState, useContext, useReducer, useEffect} from 'react';
import cartData from '../component/data'; //this is the source file for the product list//
import customReducer from './reducer';   //the file that handles the useReducer


const Appcontext = React.createContext();

const initialState = {
loading: false,
cart: cartData,
total: 0,
amount: 0,

}

const AppProvider = ({children}) =>{

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(customReducer, initialState);

const increaseProduct = (id) =>{
    dispatch({type: "INCREASE_PRODUCT", payload: id})
}

const decreaseProduct = (id) =>{
    dispatch({type: "DECREASE_PRODUCT", payload: id})
}
return(
    <Appcontext.Provider value={{... 
    state,
    clearShopCart,
     clearShopCart,
     removeProduct,
     decreaseProduct,
     increaseProduct,
    }}>
            {children}
    </Appcontext.Provider>
   )

  }

   export const useGlobalContext = () =>{
    return useContext(Appcontext)
  }

  export {Appcontext, AppProvider}
```

**useReducer file**

```
 const customReducer = (state, action) => {
 if(action.type === 'CLEAR_SHOPP_CART'){
     return{...state, cart: []}
 }
 if(action.type === 'REMOVE_ITEM'){
     const newProducts = state.cart.filter((singleProduct) => singleProduct.id !== 
  action.payload)
     return{...state, cart: newProducts}
 }

 **if(action.type === "INCREASE_PRODUCT"){
     let newValue = state.cart.map((singleProduct) => {
         if(singleProduct.id === action.payload){
            return {... singleProduct, amount: singleProduct.amount + 1}
         }
         return singleProduct
     });
        console.log(newValue)
       return {...state, cart: newValue}** //these codes on bold format are the codes that 
          increases by 1 each time the button is clicked//

  
   }
   return state
   }

   export default customReducer;
```

**The home file where the codes are rendered**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {HiShoppingCart} from 'react-icons/hi';
import {MdKeyboardArrowUp} from 'react-icons/md';
import {RiArrowDownSLine} from 'react-icons/ri';
import { useGlobalContext } from '../component/context';

export default function Home() {
const {cart, amount, total, clearShopCart, removeProduct, decreaseProduct, increaseProduct} = 
useGlobalContext();

  {cart.map((singleData) => {
           const {id, title, price, img} = singleData;
           return(
               <>
              
               <div key={id} className='product-container'>
                   <div className='img-container'>
                        <img src={img} alt={title} />
                        <div className='product-text-container'>
                            <h4>{title}</h4>
                            < h4>${price}</h4>
                            <h5 className='btn1' onClick={() => removeProduct(id)}>Remove</h5>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                   
                   <div className='item-control'>
                        <MdKeyboardArrowUp className='iconUp' onClick={() => 
                         increaseProduct(id)}/>  **//when clicked, should inrease 'amount' by 
                                                       1**//
                        <p>{amount}</p>
                        {console.log(amount)}

                        <RiArrowDownSLine className='iconDown' onClick={() => 
                        decreaseProduct(id)}/>

                   </div>
                    
                
               </div>

             
               
               </>
               )

           
            })}
```

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found the solution. I needed to destructure the 'amount' object coming from the product array. That way, I was able to increase the individual products' amount. It should be like this while destructuring the array:

```
{cart.map((singleData) => {
       const {id, title, price, img, amount} = singleData;
```